# How could I update this deprecated code for batch prediction using sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker, deprecated

Let me explain my problem:

I have to update the code of a notebook that used version 1.x of sagemaker to make a batch prediction from an xgboost endpoint that has been generated in aws SageMaker.
After defining a dataframe called ordered_data, when trying to run this:

```py
def batch_predict(data, xgb_predictor, rows=500):
   
    split_array = np.array_split(data, int(data.shape[0] / float(rows) + 1))
    predicates = ''
    for array in split_array:
        new_predictions = xgb_predictor.predictor.predict(array).decode('utf-8').
        predictions = predictions + '\n' + predictions_new
    predictions = predictions.replace('\n', ',')
    predictions = predictions.replace(',,', ',')

    return np.fromstring(predictions[1:], sep=',')
```

```py
def get_predictions(sorted_data, xgb_predictor):

    xgb_predictor.content_type = 'text/csv'. 
    xgb_predictor.serializer = csv_serializer 
    xgb_predictor.deserializer = None

    #predictions = batch_predict(ordered_data.as_matrix(), xgb_predictor) # get the scores for each piece of data
    predictions = batch_predict(ordered_data.values, xgb_predictor)
    predictions = pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns=['score'])

    return predictions
```

```py
xgb_predictor = sagemaker.predictor.RealTimePredictor(endpoint_name='sagemaker-xgboost-2023-01-18')

predictions = get_predictions(sorted_data, xgb_predictor)
predictions2 = pd.concat([predictions, raw_data[[['order_id']]]], axis=1).
```

I've checked the documentation of sagemaker v2, and tried to update many things, and also I've run the code !sagemaker-upgrade-v2 --in-file file.ipynb --out-file file2.ipynb
but nothing works.

I get several errors like:
'content_type' property of object 'deprecated_class..DeprecatedClass' has no setter.
If I delete the line where I define content_type, I get: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ACCEPT'.
and so on.
I need to update all this code but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker [RealTimePredictor](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/v1.72.0/api/inference/predictors.html#sagemaker.predictor.RealTimePredictor) class has serializer and deserializer parameters in Python SDK V2, behavior for serialization of input data and deserialization of result data can be configured through initializer arguments.

Note: The csv_serializer, json_serializer, npy_serializer, csv_deserializer, json_deserializer, and numpy_deserializer objects have been deprecated in v2

```
serializer=CSVSerializer(),
deserializer=JSONDeserializer()
```